# How to HIDE everything in PUBLISH metabox except Move to Trash & PUBLISH button

Tags: metabox, publish

I have a custom post type (called contacts).
Since this post type is not working like a post, I don't want to show SAVE DRAFT, PREVIEW, Status, Visibility or Publish Date.

The only options I want to show are PUBLISH & Move to Trash buttons.

Is there a way to hide these other options? If not, how do I create a new PUBLISH & Move to Trash that I can add to a new metabox?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can simply hide the options using CSS. This will add a display:none style to the misc and minor publishing actions on the post.php and post-new.php pages. It checks for a specific post type as well since all post types use these two files.

```
function hide_publishing_actions(){
        $my_post_type = 'POST_TYPE';
        global $post;
        if($post->post_type == $my_post_type){
            echo '
                <style type="text/css">
                    #misc-publishing-actions,
                    #minor-publishing-actions{
                        display:none;
                    }
                </style>
            ';
        }
}
add_action('admin_head-post.php', 'hide_publishing_actions');
add_action('admin_head-post-new.php', 'hide_publishing_actions');
```

Comment: Brian - Thanks for the quick response. I tried the function, replacing 'POST_TYPE' with the name of the custom post type (contacts), but nothing is removed when I go the the edit/add new pages.

Comment: Check out my latest edit. It should fix the issue. :)

Comment: That is brilliant - this has opened up a whole new way to remove stuff I don't want showing!! Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help out :)

Comment: Just to point it out: you can remove a level of indentation for your code by simply doing `if ( $post->post_type != $my_post_type ){ return; }` at the beginning. No need to have the entirety of your code wrapped in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

In this example you can easily set on which post types you want to hide the publishing options, the example hides them for the build-in pots type type `page` and the custom post type `cpt_portfolio`.

```
/**
 * Hides with CSS the publishing options for the types page and cpt_portfolio
 */
function wpse_36118_hide_minor_publishing() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if( in_array( $screen->id, array( 'page', 'cpt_portfolio' ) ) ) {
        echo '<style>#minor-publishing { display: none; }</style>';
    }
}

// Hook to admin_head for the CSS to be applied earlier
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse_36118_hide_minor_publishing' );
```

---

## Important update

I would also suggest you force a post status of "Published" to avoid saving posts as drafts:

```
/**
 * Sets the post status to published
 */
function wpse_36118_force_published( $post ) {
    if( 'trash' !== $post[ 'post_status' ] ) { /* We still want to use the trash */
        if( in_array( $post[ 'post_type' ], array( 'page', 'cpt_portfolio' ) ) ) {
            $post['post_status'] = 'publish';
        }
        return $post;
    }
}

// Hook to wp_insert_post_data
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'wpse_36118_force_published' );
```