# How to remove Filters from post admin page?

Tags: custom-post-types, filters

On a custom post type, I want to remove the filters that show up on /edit.php (where all of the posts are listed out).

I have a custom taxonomy that shows up as a filter that I WANT to keep, but I want to REMOVE the 'Show all dates' and 'View all categories' filters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very similar question to the one you posted here: [How to HIDE everything in PUBLISH metabox except Move to Trash & PUBLISH button](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36118/how-to-hide-everything-in-publish-metabox-except-move-to-trash-publish-button) Please check my answer. You would simply need to add the IDs of the elements you wish to hide.

You can traverse the DOM to target the elements you need:

```
#posts-filter .tablenav select[name=m],
#posts-filter .tablenav select[name=cat],
#posts-filter .tablenav #post-query-submit{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Brian, the code from the other post works when this is added: add_action('admin_head-edit.php', 'hide_publishing_actions');   But, I am not able to get the Show All Dates removed because it does not have an ID or Class assigned to it. Any ideas?

Comment: Check out my latest edit.

Answer (score 9):

There is a filter for the dropdown dates since WP 3.7.0 (sorry I did not check the others but I assume they also have filters).

The filter is: `months_dropdown_results`

This example below removed the dates dropdown from the admin *pages* filter but not for *posts*.

```
function remove_date_drop(){

$screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( 'page' == $screen->post_type ){
        add_filter('months_dropdown_results', '__return_empty_array');
    }
}

add_action('admin_head', 'remove_date_drop');
```

Answer (score 1):

Hiding by css also affect other post/page types. At least I was able to remove Actions for an specific cpt using this hook

`add_filter('bulk_actions-edit-mycpt', '__return_empty_array');`

Answer (score 1):

Since WordPress 4.2.0, removing the **All Dates** dropdown filter menu is much easier thanks to the [`disable_months_dropdown`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/disable_months_dropdown/) filter.

To disable the dates filter menu everywhere, use the `__return_true` helper:

```php
add_filter('disable_months_dropdown', '__return_true');
```

To disable the dates filter menu for a specific post_type, use a simple function like this:

```php
add_filter(
    'disable_months_dropdown',
    function ($disable, $type) {
        return $type === 'my_post_type';
    },
    10,
    2,
);
```